# Worklight project - dojo query() use variable instead of a text

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo

If i use this dojo instruction, and all work correctly.

```
sampleStore.query({ item_name:/^aa/}, {sort: [{attribute: "des"}]});
```

How can i use a variable(filter) instead of "aa" such  as

```
var filter="aa";
sampleStore.query({ item_name:/^filter/}, {sort: [{attribute: "des"}]});//don't work
```

or

```
sampleStore.query({ item_name:/^"+filter+"/}, {sort: [{attribute: "des"}]});//don't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Strings in JavaScript regular expressions. If you want to do something like that you need to use `new RegExp()` to create a regular expression based on a string.

```js
sampleStore.query({ item_name: new RegExp('^' + filter) }, {sort: [{attribute: "des"}]});
```

**NOTE**: If you use regular expressions this way, you cannot add the delimiter `/`. If you need to add modifiers like `i` (case insensitive `/.*/i`), you can do that by using:

```js
new RegExp(".*", i);
```

Comment: Thank you. This work :sampleStore.query({ desc:new RegExp("^test")}); but i don't undertand, how add the case insensitive condition to this RegExp

Comment: new RegExp("^test", "i");

Comment: Indeed, like @Philippe (and I) said, by adding your modifier as the second parameter of the `RegExp`. If you use `new RegExp("test", "i");` it's the same as `/test/i`.

Comment: var reg=new RegExp("^"+filter, "i");